# Adujst html to iframe size

Tags: html, css, iframe

So i have this issue. i'm tryng to adjust and html inside an iframe , and i keep bangging my head arround this. the Html contains an image slider and my objective is that the image slider fills the entire iframe.

this is the html of the iframe, targgeting the index1.html:

```
<iframe height="520px" width="100%" src="index1.html" name="frame" style="border: none"></iframe>
```

and here is the css that controls the index1 image slider dimensions

```
body{
    padding: 0px;
    margin:0px;
}

#container{

width: 1298px;
height: 520px;
padding: 0px;
margin-top:0px;
margin-left:0px;

}

#slider{
position: center;
overflow: hidden;
width: 1298px;
height: 520px;
padding: 0px;
margin-top:0px;
margin-left:0px;
}
```

Every time i try to adjust te height of both image slider and it's container, the i frame creates a scroll.

The results i'm getting is the following: 
[please view image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQEXl.jpg)

That red marked grey area is the remaining of the iframe that i can't get the image slide fit into.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use either `scrolling="no"` or `overflow: hidden;`

```
<iframe height="520px" width="100%" src="index1.html" name="frame" scrolling="no" style="border: none; overflow: hidden;"></iframe>
```

You should probably look and see if some part of the "index1.html" is wider than the image slider. Pay attention to margins, padding, and borders. I would look into this before you try my suggestion above, because if there is some part of the content being hidden it may cause you issues later.